# Javascript default arguments with block scoping fails on iOS only

Tags: javascript, ios, ecmascript-6, scope

```js
try {
  const val = 'correct value';
  (() => {
    ((arg = val) => {
      const val = 'ignored value';
      alert(arg);
    })();
  })();
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

On OS X Chrome, OS X Safari, Android Chrome, Windows Chrome, Windows Firefox, and *even* Windows Edge, it alerts "correct value". On iOS Safari and iOS Chrome, it alerts "Can't find variable: val".

The following snippets all work on iOS:

Not using default argument (snippet 2):

```js
try {
  const val = 'correct value';
  (() => {
    alert(val);
    (() => {
      const val = 'wrong value';
    })();
  })();
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

No nested functions (snippet 3):

```js
try {
  const val = 'correct value';
  ((arg = val) => {
    const val = 'ignored value';
    alert(val || 'wrong value');
  })();
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

Not overriding variable (snippet 4):

```js
try {
  const val = 'correct value';
  (() => {
    ((arg = val) => {
      alert(arg);
    })();
  })();
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

Block scope instead of function (snippet 5):

```js
try {
  const val = 'correct value';
  {
    ((arg = val) => {
      const val = 'ignored value';
      alert(arg);
    })();
  }
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

Based on the snippet 3, it's clear that the `val` in `arg = val` should come from the parent scope, not the scope of the inner function.

In the first snippet, the browser can't find `val` in the current scope, but instead of checking the ancestor scopes, it uses the child scope, which causes the temporal dead zone.

Is this an iOS bug or am I misunderstanding the proper JS behavior?

This bug is occurring in our Webpack+Babel+Terser output, so we can't just rewrite the code to avoid this bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an unwanted consequence of a buggy implementation of the [Param default values and their TDZs](https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#parameter-default-values-and-the-temporal-dead-zone). I suspect that iOS Safari thinks you're trying to assign to something you have't initialized yet.

For reference -- the error location:

[image]

---

**Workaround 1**
Don't initialize an inner scope const w/ the same name as the default param & the outer scope's one

```
try {
    const val = 'correct value';
    (() => {
        ((arg = val) => {
            const val_ = 'ignored value';       // <----
            alert(arg);
        })();
    })();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error('msg', err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

**Workaround 2**

Force `const` to `let`:

```
try {
    let val = 'correct value';                 // <----
    (() => {
        ((arg = val) => {
            const val = 'ignored value';
            alert(arg);
        })();
    })();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error('msg', err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```

**Workaround 3**
Don't reinitialize `const val` in the innermost closure at all:

```
try {
    const val = 'correct value';
    (() => {
        ((arg = val) => {
            // const val = 'ignored value';      // <--
            alert(arg);
        })();
    })();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error('msg', err.message || 'Unknown error');
}
```